# Multiple and selected attribute not displaying in browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, chromium, html5

I've been watching HTML5 tutorial videos by a guy named Bob Tabor and have come across a little problem I just can't find an answer for, so I'm sorry if I'm asking the wrong people. I can't figure out if it's a problem with the code, browser or operating system.

I'm using the "select" tag with the "multiple" attribute included. With the "multiple" attribute included in the "select" tag, "selected" attributes I place within the "option" tags do not display at all on my computer (but displays fine without the "multiple" attribute). I'm using Chromium and Firefox on Ubuntu 12.04.
However, I tried exactly the same code on someone else's computer (Google Chrome on a Windows os) and it displayed perfectly.

Any ideas?

Comment: *What tutorial video... there a quite a few...* Please can you link to the video you are on about, as well display your HTML 'code' as well (just the relevant bit - if it is massive, you could use use the [paste bin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/). *Wow, its been ages since I did websites...*

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/HTML5-CSS3-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Creating-Forms-10 About 16 minutes onwards, the code for the crust dropbox.

Comment: <form method="post">

<p>Crust
<select name="crust" multiple>
  <option value="c1">Normal</option>
  <option value="c2" selected>Chicago Deep Dish</option>
  <option value="c3">New York Thin</option>
  </select>
</p>

</form>   - Just that part.

Answer (score 0):

Neat tutorial - **just why does everything have to be done in Internet Explorer** though! Even if you do use Windows, it is just an annoyance....

Right, I have tested your code on my computer *(using  Google Chrome 31* (probably) *and Firefox 25)*.

For this:
`<form method="post"> <p>Crust <select name="crust" multiple> <option value="c1">Normal</option> <option value="c2" selected>Chicago Deep Dish</option> <option value="c3">New York Thin</option> </select> </p> </form>`

I got this *(Firefox left, Chrome right)*:

[image: multiple]

Without `multiple`, I got this with dropdown boxes:

[image: no-multiple]

So the html works, but it may be the browser that is at fault. You could

1) Update your browsers - the relevant tags are supposed to be compatible with Firefox and Chrome (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) ), but it can sometimes take a while for the Linux distributions of those browsers to catch up and work properly.

2) Test it in different ways. Try testing it with the html on its own (with none of the fieldsets and stuff that appear in the tutorial), or by placing it in a properly syntaxed webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="" type="image/gif" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="created" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-uk">
</head>
<body lang="en-gb" >
<form method="post"> <p>Crust <select name="crust" multiple> <option value="c1">Normal</option> <option value="c2" selected>Chicago Deep Dish</option> <option value="c3">New York Thin</option> </select> </p> </form>
</body>
</html>
```